# AWS S3 stored images link is not working in Gmail newsletter

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, gmail, newsletter

I'm trying to send a newsletter using Django SMTP.But image links in the newsletter are dead in Gmail.
[image: Image link broken]

I'm using a custom domain name and the images are stored in a public S3 bucket.

The html code for newsletter:

```
class Mail(generics.ListAPIView):
    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        subject = 'Newsletter'
        message = ''
        html_content = f'''
        <!doctype html>
            <html lang=en>
                <head>
                    <meta charset=utf-8>
                    <title>Test</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <div style="width:100%;background-color:#F3F2EF;display:flex">
                        <div style="width:430px;display:block;margin:1rem auto;background-color:white;padding:1rem">
                            <div style="display:flex;height:60px;width:100%;align-items:center;">
                                <a href="https://www.example.com" style="display:flex;margin:auto"><img src="https://www.example.com/image.jpg" style="display:block" alt="logo" title="img" width="150px" height="50px" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </body>
            </html>
        '''
        from_email = os.getenv('MAILADDRESS')
        to = 'user@gmail.com'
        
        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, message, from_email, [to])
        msg.content_subtype = 'html'
        msg.mixed_subtype = 'related'
        msg.attach_alternative(html_content,"text/html")
        msg.send()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Is it okay for other recipients, and only bad for Gmail users?

Comment: I haven't tried with other recipients yet.

Comment: Try with a normal (non-Gmail) recipient. Gmail does strange things to images in email messages to prevent people using them for tracking purposes. You can then figure out whether the problem is with the email, or with Gmail.

Comment: I tried the same HTML code with other S3 bucket images and it worked in Gmail.Only the bucket with Django integration is giving this problem

Comment: If you copy the URL for the image and paste it into a browser Address Bar, does the image appear correctly?

Comment: Yes, it does appear.

Comment: Never mind. I copied my bucket content into a new bucket and applied the same configurations and it is now working. I think there might be issues with the bucket. Thank you John for responding.